# Best practice for admin panels in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, architecture

Hi I'm wondering how to design the architecture of my admin panel on my site. I've made an AdminController that can only be accessed by the admin role so that works.

I've been thinking about making the sidebar panel a shared layout, since it is going to be used by multiple views.

I'm looking to use [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/dashboard/) bootstrap template. When navigating around should each option in the sidebar link to an individual view? This is where I'm confused because maintainability-wise it seems best to have a bunch of views for each concern right?